# Corollary from Eberlein - Smulyan theorem

Tags: functional-analysis, weak-convergence

**Theorem.**  *If $X$ is reflexive Banach space, then each bounded sequance in $X$ has a weakly convergent subsequance.*

It follows that if $X$ is a reflexive Banach space and the sequnace $(u_n)$ is bounded, then we can find a subsequance $(u_{n_{k}})\subset (u_{n})$ and an element $u\in X$ such that $u_{n_{k}}\rightarrow u$ weakly in $X$. **How to prove that if the limit is independent of the subsequance extracted, then the whole sequance $(u_{n})$ converges weakly to $u$ ?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the classic "double subsequence trick".

Prove the contrapositive.  Suppose $u_n$ does not converge weakly to $u$.  Then there is a weakly open neighborhood $V$ of $u$ such that infinitely many of the $u_n$, call them $u_{n_1}, u_{n_2}, \dots$, are outside $V$.  But this subsequence $u_{n_k}$ is again bounded, so it has a weakly convergent subsequence $u_{n_{k_j}}$, whose limit cannot equal $u$.

Comment: How do you know that such a neighborhood exitsts? It is clear while considering a sequance convergent with respect to the norm. But now, it is only weakly convergent.

Comment: @Vessemir: It's the definition of sequence convergence in any topology.  I should have said "weakly open", but everything here is with respect to the weak topology.

Comment: Now it's perfectly clear. Thank you!